# Is there a way to get the cluster name of Kubernetes in Grafana variables with prometheus data source?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to get the cluster name with a variable in Grafana and I need it to be retrieved from the prometheus data source.

I tried with `label_values(kube_pod_info, cluster)` and `label_values(up, cluster)` but it's not working for me

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure the label name is really "cluster"? I use "label_values(up, instance)" instead.

Comment: Hello the  instance label gives me a bunch of different IPs

Comment: And do you have a label called "cluster" in these metrics?

Comment: No, I don't have the label cluster in those metrics

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "cluster" label defined in the "kube_pod_info" metric.

To resolve this you can just use the "instance" label instead or create a "cluster" label in the Prometheus configuration using the "instance" label to map the IPs to known cluster names, for example.